# How to set a default props value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a Weather project, I've displayed main temp(temperature), min temp, max temp, hourly and daily temp. Each temp value has celcius as well as fahrenheit unit toggled. Min and Max temp has default value set to celcius, but, not others. Whenever refreshed all temp values except Min and Max are set to fahrenheit values.

Following are the require files

1. App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Weather from "./components/Weather";
import Spinner from "./components/Spinner";
import {
  ToastContainer,
  toast,
  Slide,
  Zoom,
  Flip,
  Bounce
} from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import DailyHourly from "./components/forecast/DailyHourly";

// weatherbit
const API_KEY3 = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;

// weatherbit current, daily and hourly forecast
const CURRENT_API = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?`;

const FORECAST_API = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?`;

const HOURLY_API = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/hourly?`;

const sectionStyle = {
  background: "inherit",
  opacity: "0.42",
  filter: "blur(1.2px)",
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  backgroundPosition: "center",
  position: "absolute",
  background: "#747d8c",
  boxShadow: "2rem 0 1rem 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
  border: "3px solid transparent"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      lat: "",
      lon: "",
      description: "",
      maxTempCel: "",
      maxTempFahr: "",
      minTempCel: "",
      minTempFahr: "",
      hourlyforecast: "",
      unit: "C",
      cel: "",
      fahr: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: "C"
    });
    // Tracking the location and
    // Setting the state of latitude and longitude values
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async (position) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            lat: position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3),
            lon: position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3)
          },
          () => {
            this.fetchWeather();
          }
        );
      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error(`${error.message}`, {
          autoClose: 3000
        });
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      }
    );
  };

  onUnitChange = (newUnit) => {
    //console.log("UNIT SHOWN", newUnit);
    this.setState({
      unit: newUnit
    });
  };

  fetchWeather = async () => {
    const { lat, lon } = this.state;

    // First it changes from M to I and then it doesn't change
    //console.log("UNIT TYPE", unitType);

    // Current Weather
    fetch(
      `${CURRENT_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&key=${API_KEY3}`
      // `${CURRENT_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&key=${API_KEY3}&units=${unitType}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        //console.log("Current Weather", responseJson);
        try {
          this.setState(
            {
              cel: Math.round(responseJson.data[0].temp),
              fahr: Math.round(responseJson.data[0].temp * 1.8 + 32),
              // temp: responseJson.data[0].temp,
              isLoading: false
            },
            () => {
              localStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify(this.state));
            }
          );
        } catch {
          toast.error("Error Code 429");
        }
      });

    // Forecast Weather - Daily and Min Max
    fetch(`${FORECAST_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&days=6&key=${API_KEY3}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        //console.log("Daily Weather", responseJson);
        try {
          this.setState(
            {
              dailyforecast: responseJson.data,
              precip: responseJson.data[0].pop,
              maxTempCel: Math.round(responseJson.data[0].max_temp),
              maxTempFahr: Math.round(responseJson.data[0].max_temp * 1.8) + 32,
              minTempCel: Math.round(responseJson.data[0].min_temp),
              minTempFahr: Math.round(responseJson.data[0].min_temp * 1.8) + 32,
              isLoading: false
            },
            () => {
              console.log("DAILY", this.state.dailyforecast);
              localStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify(this.state));
            }
          );
        } catch {
          toast.error("Too many requests");
        }
      });

    // Forecast Weather - Hourly
    fetch(`${HOURLY_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&hours=10&key=${API_KEY3}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        try {
          this.setState(
            {
              hourlyforecast: responseJson.data,
              isLoading: false
            },
            () => {
              localStorage.setItem("weather", JSON.stringify(this.state));
            }
          );
        } catch {
          toast.error("Please wait some time");
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoading, dailyforecast, hourlyforecast, precip } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "1.8em" }}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-4 form-container">
              <ToastContainer
                transition={Bounce}
                className="toast-background"
              />
            </div>

            {isLoading ? (
              <Spinner />
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                <div className="col-sm-8 image-container">
                  {/* Weather Card */}
                  <div className="background">
                    <div className="container">
                      <div
                        id="card"
                        className="weather"
                        style={sectionStyle}
                      ></div>

                      <div
                        id="card"
                        className="weather2"
                        style={{ background: "" }}
                      >
                        <div className="details">
                          {/* Weather Details */}
                          <div className="content" style={{ width: "105px" }}>
                            <Weather
                              cel={this.state.cel}
                              fahr={this.state.fahr}
                              maxTempCel={this.state.maxTempCel}
                              maxTempFahr={this.state.maxTempFahr}
                              minTempCel={this.state.minTempCel}
                              minTempFahr={this.state.minTempFahr}
                              changeUnit={this.onUnitChange}
                              unit={this.state.unit}
                            />
                          </div>

                          {/* Forecast Cards */}

                          <div
                            className="content"
                            style={{ width: "400px", marginTop: "-40px" }}
                          >
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <DailyHourly
                              unit={this.state.unit}
                              timezone={this.state.timezone}
                              dailyforecast={dailyforecast}
                              hourlyforecast={hourlyforecast}
                            />
                          </div>
                          {/* Forecast Cards Ends*/}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  {/* Video Background Starts */}

                  {/* Video Background Ends */}
                </div>
                {/* Weather Card Ends */}
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

2. Weather.js (Display Weather temperature)

```
import React from "react";
import "./Weather.css";
import uparrow from "../images/up-arrow.png";
import downarrow from "../images/down-arrow2.png";
import CelToFahr from "./CelToFahr";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import CelToFa from "./CelToFa";

const Weather = (props) => {
  // For CelToFahr component
  const sendNewUnitToParent = (newUnit) => {
    //console.log("Unit I get", newUnit);
    props.changeUnit(newUnit);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <CelToFa onSelectedTempUnit={newTempUnit} /> */}
      <CelToFahr onUnitChange={sendNewUnitToParent} />
      {/* {props.temp && props.temp === 0 ? (
        <div className="glow">
          {Math.trunc(props.temp)}°<h5>{props.unit === "C" ? "C" : "F"}</h5>{" "}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="glow">
          {Math.trunc(props.temp)}°<h5>{props.unit === "C" ? "C" : "F"}</h5>
        </div>
      )} */}
      {console.log("PROPS", props)}
      <>
        <CountUp
          start={props.unit === "C" ? props.fahr : props.cel}
          end={props.unit === "F" ? props.fahr : props.cel}
          duration={2}
        >
          {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
            <h1 style={{ color: "white" }} ref={countUpRef}></h1>
          )}
        </CountUp>
        {}° {props.unit === "C" ? "C" : "F"}
      </>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <div style={{ width: "50%", display: "inline-block" }}>
          {props.minTempCel && props.minTempFahr === 0 ? (
            <h6 style={{ color: "white" }}>
              <strong>
                <img src={downarrow} />
                0°
              </strong>
            </h6>
          ) : (
            <strong>
              <img src={downarrow} />
              <CountUp
                start={
                  props.unit === "F" ? props.minTempCel : props.minTempFahr
                }
                end={props.unit === "C" ? props.minTempCel : props.minTempFahr}
                duration={2}
              >
                {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
                  <h6 style={{ color: "white" }} ref={countUpRef}></h6>
                )}
              </CountUp>
              {}° {props.unit === "C" ? "C" : "F"}
            </strong>
          )}
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "50%", display: "inline-block" }}>
          {props.maxTempCel && props.maxTempFahr === 0 ? (
            <h6 style={{ color: "white" }}>
              <strong>
                <img src={uparrow} />
                0°
              </strong>
            </h6>
          ) : (
            <strong>
              <img src={uparrow} />
              <CountUp
                start={
                  props.unit === "F" ? props.maxTempCel : props.maxTempFahr
                }
                end={props.unit === "C" ? props.maxTempCel : props.maxTempFahr}
                duration={2}
              >
                {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
                  <h6 style={{ color: "white" }} ref={countUpRef}></h6>
                )}
              </CountUp>
              {}° {props.unit === "C" ? "C" : "F"}
            </strong>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      {<hr style={{ color: "white" }} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Weather;
```

3. CelToFahr.js (C to F toggle button)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./CelToFahr.css";

class CelToFahr extends Component {
  state = {
    celOn: false,
    unit: "F"
  };

  changeUnit = () => {
    this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn });
    const newUnit = this.state.celOn === false ? "F" : "C";
    this.props.onUnitChange(newUnit);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="toggle-button-cover">
        <div className="button r" id="button-3">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            className="checkbox"
            onClick={this.changeUnit}
          />
          <div className="knobs"></div>
          <div className="layer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CelToFahr;
```

Rest of the files are available in codesandbox.
Following is the link [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-edison-yd9zk)

My intention is to set default values to celcius. Any appropriate solution?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking; there's `defaultProps`, does that not do what you want?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.weatherbit.io/api/requests) states that we can pass the "units" parameter to the api. Maybe add `?units=C` to your requests. `const CURRENT_API = https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?units=C;` also, please reduce your code sample to a [mcve]; as it stands you're just kinda dumping your entire project out which makes it more difficult to diagnose the problem as it's hidden in a bunch of code that's not relavent to it.

Comment: The state has unit set to C as default what other defaults you need?

Comment: Yyour ternary operators are wrong in several places. For examply in Weather`props.unit === "F" ? props.minTempCel : props.minTempFahr` that is saying when the unit is "F" show the min CELCIUS temp. Same issue in DailyForcast and HourlyForcast.

Comment: Please refer codesandbox. When you refresh you can see some are set to celcius while some to fahrenheit value.

Comment: I mean main temp, min temp and other values must show celcius values and not fahrenheit on loading

Comment: @Pranav did you see my comment about your ternary operators being wrong? They are making it so fahrenheit is being shown when celsius is selected.